# Overload resolution without a parameter list on class member access?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct X
{
    void f(double) {}
    static void f(int) {}
};

int main()
{
    X x;

    auto y = x.f;
}
```

gcc gives:

```
error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘x.X::f’
```

`x.f` is a *class member access* `postfix-expression` documented in 5.2.5 [expr.ref]

It effectively says:

> If `f` is a (possibly overloaded) member function, function overload resolution (13.3) is used to deter-
>   mine whether `x.f` refers to a static or a non-static member function.  (from N3485 5.2.5.4.3 )

How can overload resolution be applied here - `x.f` doesn't have a parameter list with which to do overload resolution?

Or am I missing something?

**Update:** If I change the `auto y = x.f` line to an `expression-statement`:

```
- auto y = x.f;
+ x.f;
```

then gcc instead complains:

```
error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function
```

Comment: Yep, found that right after posting the comment, sorry

Comment: IMO you could send this issue to the Committee/mailing list; [expr.ref]4/ is at least imprecise, arguably it's even wrong (*overload resolution* vs [over.over]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're right in that the Standard isn't precise at this point:

[expr.ref]/4

> If f is a (possibly overloaded) member function, function overload resolution (13.3) is used to determine whether `x.f` refers to a static or a non-static member function.

As the first sub-bullet states:

> If it refers to a static member function and the type of E2 is “function of parameter-type-list returning T”, then E1.E2 is an lvalue; the expression designates the static member function. The type of E1.E2 is the same type as that of E2, namely “function of parameter-type-list returning T”.

That is, `x.f` can be used to initialize a function ptr if `f` is static, whereas (see following sub-bullet) if `f` is not static, it can only be used in a function-call expression.

But actually, overload resolution **is not performed** to select an overload from the name of an overloaded function outside the context of a function-call-expression:

[over.over]/1

> A use of an overloaded function name without arguments is resolved in certain contexts to a function, a pointer to function or a pointer to member function for a specific function from the overload set. [...] **The function selected is the one whose type is identical to the function type of the target type required in the context.**

That is, an exact match, not invoking the overload resolution mechanism described in [over.match]. Therefore [expr.ref]/4 is incomplete, is doesn't describe your case of using `x.f` to initialize a function pointer/reference.

As the `auto` keyword doesn't specify a target type (or according to [dcl.spec.auto]/6, the mechanism to deduce the type for `auto` fails), you cannot use `auto y = x.f;`:

- `x.f` refers to a set of overloaded functions
- a function from this set needs to be selected
- selection is based upon overload resolution (in a function-call-expression, not applicable here) or based on the target type
- there's no target type here, or rather, the target type is equivalent to a template argument, therefore type deduction for `auto` fails

---

The type of `x.f` therefore is

- in the context of a function call, directly refer to [expr.ref]/4
- otherwise, it is a set of overloaded functions, from which then the function is selected according to [over.over], whereupon the type is determined according to [expr.ref]/4

Answer (score 2):

Even if there's only one `x.f` valid in this context, the compiler *must* do the overload resolution before determining if the function is static or not.

> *§5.2.5* « If E2 is a (possibly overloaded) member function, function overload
>   resolution (13.3) is used to determine whether E1.E2 refers to a
>   static or a non-static member function. »

The overload resolution mechanism (as described in §13.3 and §13.4) need a valid context to select the correct candidate :

> *§13.4.1* « A use of an overloaded function name without arguments is resolved in certain contexts to a function, a pointer to function or a
>   pointer to member function for a specific function from the overload
>   set »

`auto y = x.f;` is not a valid resolution context, you either have to drop the `auto` keyword or to use a `static_cast` to force the overload resolution :

```
X x;

auto y = static_cast<void (&)(int)>(x.f);
y(1);

auto z = static_cast<void (X::*)(double)>(&X::f);
(x.*z)(1.);
```

Note that you can't have a reference to a non-static member, only a pointer, as per *§ 8.3.3* :

> There is no “reference-to-member” type in C++

Comment: Yes but what is the type and value category of the expression `x.f` in the above, where is this documented in the standard?  It seems the standard requires overload resolution on `x.f` before it documents what exactly `x.f` is?  Unless I am missing something

Comment: this is only for static function. but what about for member function?static cast is UB then.

Comment: The compiler needs to do the overload resolution **before** determining if `x.f` is static or not. It can't do the overload resolution without any constraint on the function signature. if you don't give parameter type constraint, then you have to make a cast to constrain the function signature.

Comment: @Koushik It wouldn't be *UB* since the cast won't work on non-static member, that wouldn't compile. A pointer signature to a non-static function member  would be `void (X::*)(int)` not `void (*)(int)`.